# Why a series-wired light bulbs consume less energy than a parallel-wired light bulbs?

Tags: electric-circuits, power

Why a series-wired light bulbs  consume less energy than a parallel-wired light bulbs ?

Comment: You have to show the two circuits and the assumptions that you are making. E.g. are you assuming that all the light bulbs have the same resistance? Both circuits are driven by batteries with the same voltage? Or perhaps they are driven by current sources providing the same current instead?

Comment: Hint: The mains supply to your home is a (notionally) constant voltage supply.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you connect two identical light bulbs to a ten volt supply. If you connect them in parallel, each bulb has the full ten volts across it. If you connect them in series, each light bulb has five volts across it (because the midpoint of the two bulbs will be at a midpoint voltage).

Since there is only half the voltage across the bulbs in series, only half the current will flow. With half the voltage and half the current, each bulb will only emit 1/4 the power (since power is voltage times current).

This is all very oversimplified, but should allow the conclusion to make intuitive sense.

Answer (score 2):

As a counterpoint to David Schwartz's answer which assumes a constant voltage source, here is what happens if you have a constant current source instead.

In the parallel case, the current splits so each of the bulbs gets a fraction of the current. The power is $I^2 R$. Let's assume two bulbs: then the current through each is $I/2$, so the power for each is $({I \over 2})^2 R = {I^2 \over4} R$ so the power for both is twice that: ${1\over2} I^2 R$.

In the series case, the current is $I$ through each resistor, so the total power is $2 I^2 R$ which is *more* than in the parallel case.

Admittedly, a constant voltage source is much more common, but it is important to state your assumptions clearly and avoid making unwarranted generalizations (e.g. "resistances in series consume less power" - well, no).

Answer (score 0):

When connected in series, resistance of the circuit increases.  Equal current flows through all the resistors.

Therefore, the resistor having more power has less resistance,$$R=\frac{V^2}{P} \,.$$That resistor this receives less electrical energy,$$E=I^2 \times R  T \,,$$ so it glows dim.

By contrast, connecting the resistors in parallel causes the resistor to have more power and glow brighter,$$E=\frac{V^2}{R} T \,.$$

Answer (score -4):

I think a bulb would consume the same power no matter how you connect it provided you give it the supply voltage it is rated for.

Comment: Not true: see @David Schwartz answer for the constant voltage case and my answer for the constant current case. In both cases, series and parallel consume different amounts of power.